# I'm very new to SQL. Trying to connect two tables without an aliases

Tags: sql

```
select 
    concat(course.coursedept,',', course.coursenumber),
    concat(faculty.Facfirstname,',', faculty.Faclastname), 
    concat(student.stdfirstname,',', student.stdlastname),
    coursedesc, offterm, format
from 
    offering 
inner join 
    course on offering.Course_idCourse = course.idCourse
inner join 
    faculty on offering.Faculty_idFaculty = faculty.idFaculty
```

I want to use inner join for `concat(stdfirstname, ',', stdlastname)` with the rest of the tables, however `student` is not related to the table `offering` and `offering` only has `faculty_idfaculty` and `course_idcourse` in it.

The other table is `enrollment` which has `student_idstudent` and `offering_idoffering` in it. However I don't need enrollment, but it does have both student and offering in it.

When I run it without `concat(stdfirstname, ',', stdlastname)` it works but not with it and I need the students first and last names.

Comment: Why are you all thumbing down, I'm new to SQL? I need help so if anyone can help that would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to join student table to use any column from this table. Since student is not related to offering, course or faculty table I have used enrollment table to join student table. Please try this and let me know if you face anydifficulties.

```
select concat(course.coursedept,',', course.coursenumber),
concat(faculty.Facfirstname,',', faculty.Faclastname), 
concat(student.stdfirstname,',', student.stdlastname),
coursedesc, offterm, format
from offering 
inner join course on offering.Course_idCourse=course.idCourse
inner join faculty on offering.Faculty_idFaculty=faculty.idFaculty
inner join enrollment on offering_idoffering =idoffering
inner join student on idstudent=student_idstudent
```